# Correct way to remove a DialogFragment: dismiss() or transaction.remove()?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I still have a problem due to a `DialogFragment` used on my main activity.

I am currently using this code to remove it:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment frag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("LockDialog");

if(frag != null) {
    transaction.remove(frag);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

The problem is that I am still getting crashes due to the fact that the dialog has duplicates (meaning the dialog was not properly removed sometimes).

So my question is: is it a right way to remove a `DialogFragment` or must it be only used only for `Fragments`?

Do I have to use the `dismiss()` method  all the time?:

```
Fragment lockFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("LockDialog");

//If the dialog already exist, we dismiss it
if(lockFragment != null  && lockFragment instanceof LockDialogFragment) {
    LockDialogFragment lockDialog = (LockDialogFragment) lockFragment;
    lockDialog.dismiss();
}
```

This is currently my biggest bug on one of my apps so I want to be sure before choosing one or the other.

Thanks!

**EDIT**: I just realized my current problem is maybe due to the fact that commits can be delayed, I will add `executePendingTransactions` to see if it gets any better. 
But still it brings another question, is it necessary to call transaction.remove() if the dialog has been dismissed? Is using `dismiss()` more straightforward and safe than using the transactions?

Comment: For the person downvoting, please at least explain, I did not know my question was that obvious...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DialogFragment.dismiss()` is the correct way. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#dismiss%28%29):

> Dismiss the fragment and its dialog. If the fragment was added to the
>   back stack, all back stack state up to and including this entry will
>   be popped. Otherwise, a new transaction will be committed to remove
>   the fragment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. About `dismiss()`, are we sure that the dialog deletion is always done right away? In my code I have to remove my `DialogFragment` just before the call to `super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState)`. I want to be 100% sure this dialog won't be retained in the instance.

Comment: Not sure but I would guess not. You can always use `dismissAllowingStateLoss()`.

Comment: OK I will accept your answer for now and try it with `dismiss()` only. I will update the question later if I see the problem is still not solved.

Answer (score 0):

For showing Dialog Fragment `dialogFragment.show(transition,FocusDialogFragment.TAG);`

For dismissing dialog fragment by `dialogFragment.dismiss();`